# Simplest way to pass an object in razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm new to Razor and I'm trying to pass data from "Index.html" to "Quiz.html" but I'm struggling to put the pieces together using different tutorials. This is where I got so far. I'm trying to do it without using a service but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Thanks!

Index.html

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome, @Model.Name</h1>
    <p>This is My Quiz App</a>.</p>
    <form method="post">
        <label>What's your name?</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Visitor.Name">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Index.cs

```
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        [ViewData]
        [BindProperty]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Visitor Visitor { get; set; }

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
           Name = "Stranger";
        }

          public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Quiz", new { Visitor.Name }); 
        }
    }
}
```

Quiz.html

```
@page
@model QuizModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Quiz Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Thanks for checking my first website out, @Model.Name. Are you ready?</h1>
    <p>Let's see how much you know about me.</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Quiz.cs

```
 public class QuizModel : PageModel
    {
        [ViewData]
        [BindProperty]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Visitor Visitor { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Name = ?
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Pablo Aguirre de Souza,  if my solution can work, could you accept it as answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly submit the form from Index.cshtml to Quiz.cs with `asp-page` tag helper. Define a `OnPost` handler in `Quiz.cs`

```
public class QuizModel : PageModel
{
    [ViewData]
    [BindProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public Visitor Visitor { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        Name = Visitor.Name;
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome, @Model.Name</h1>
    <p>This is My Quiz App.</p>
    <form asp-page="Quiz" method="post">
        <label>What's your name?</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Visitor.Name">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir. It works perfectly. So if I understand well the secret is on the asp-page tag in the form? What If I want a form in the quiz page, which will also be handled in the quiz.cs?

Comment: Use [asp-page-handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0#asp-page-handler).